# How to set the CharSequence for setError()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am very new to coding. What i'm trying to do is that when someone does not write anything, use an `setError()` like "Please write your your answer." However, when someone click the text box, i want the writing to go away but the error symbol to stay. I have seen and tried solution where you override the setError to just set the picture.

```
public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);

}
```

However, with this method, i cannot set a charsequence

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the full file so that we can be sure that you are using `class`es correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can set error on click on the button say register or signin whatever is your function to go ahead. and check that the string is empty than 
set the error like

```
String str = myEditText.getText().toString();

if (str.length() == 0 || str.equals("")) {
   myEditText.setError("field can't be empty");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! However, i looked at some other answer on stack overflow and override my setError. So now, even if i choose to write something it doesnt work. I can only choose the image. So, do you know if there is anyway (ex setCharsequence o something) that will allow me to set the erroe massage in my override? Thank you very much for the response nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Simple handle in button click and show error msg like below. its work for me.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String data = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if(data.isEmpty())
            { 
              mEditText.setError(""Please write your your answer.");
              return;
            }
        }
```